# TFS Build agent for Windows Server 2016 and TFS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-server-2016

I am using TFS 2017 On Windows Server 2016 and I am trying to create new build definition but it is not able read the agent capabilities like msbuild visual studio
No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:
msbuild
visualstudio
vstest
Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.98.1

Comment: Have you checked your build agent machine? Do you have these capabilities installed on your build agent machine?

Answer (score 0):

Believe 2.112.0 was the agent version that shipped with 2017. I think the 1.x was from 2015, witch may not be compatible.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent is probably a better place to find support for this though

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio on your build agent machine, and restart the build agent. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to deploy a new agent which downloaded from your TFS 2017 directly.

Open a browser and navigate to the `Agent pools` tab for your TFS server to download the agent package (See [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts)):

```
https://{your_server}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool
```

After that, you can check the issue with the new agent:

- If the capabilities are still not there, then you can try to restart
  the agent service.
- If that still not work, then you can add the capabilities manually.